# Python ansible json output

Tags: python, json, ansible

I got the json output. How do I do I fetch key which can store as variable

sample:

```
"plays": [
{
    "tasks": [
        {
          "hosts": {
            "sw01": {
              "_ansible_no_log": false,
              "action": "set_fact",
              "ansible_facts": {
                "OS": "ios"
              },
              "changed": false
            }
          }
    ]
}]
```

Fetch variable:

```
    FACTS = output['plays'][0]['tasks'][0]['hosts']
```

like to fetch: `sw01` and store as hostname. Then fetch `OS` value. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: You just need to find value by key in nested json?

Comment: A JSON object translates to a dictionary in Python. You can enumerate the keys of a dictionary with .keys(). "sw01" is the only key in the hosts dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete version

```
import json

data = """{
        "plays": [
            {
                "tasks": [
                    {
                    "hosts": {
                                "sw01": {
                                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                                "action": "set_fact",
                                "ansible_facts": {
                                    "OS": "ios"
                                },
                                "changed": false
                                }
                    }
                    }]
            }]
        }"""

output = json.loads(data)

hosts = output['plays'][0]['tasks'][0]['hosts']
for host in hosts.keys():
    print(host)
```